# Searching special caligraphic math letters

Tags: fonts, math-mode

Trying `\mathcal{X}` or `\mathcal{S}` does not bring me the caligraphic letters i am searching for. I am searching for these "special" X'es and S'es you can see in the two following pictures:

[image: Special X]
[image: Special S]

Can anyone explain me which font or command to use to get these caligraphic letters?

Answer (score 7, accepted):

You can load the package [`mathrsfs`](http://www.ctan.org/pkg/mathrsfs). Different examples you can find in the [Comprehensive LaTeX Symbol List](http://mirrors.ctan.org/info/symbols/comprehensive/symbols-a4.pdf)

```
\documentclass{article}
\pagestyle{empty}
\usepackage{mathrsfs}
\begin{document}
$\mathscr{X}$ und $\mathscr{S}$
\end{document}
```

[image]

Comment: Thanks for the answer **and** this PDF - it will help me find some symbols like the imaginary unit i without a dot which I am searchong for :D

Comment: Christian: Try `\i`.

Comment: Don't forget that [Detexify](http://detexify.kirelabs.org/classify.html) can save you some time!